# Get a list of Pages that a specified Component has been published on (akin to 'View on Site')

Tags: core-service, web8.5, where-used

When doing a 'View on Site' from a Component in Tridion 8.5, the popup dialogue gives a list of pages that the the component has been published on (along with the Purposes):

[image]

I can see from Fiddler that this makes the following API call:

```
POST /WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Publishing.svc/GetListContainingPages HTTP/1.1
```

with the content:

```
{"id":"tcm:1135-11570","instruction":{"includeWorkflow":true,"resolvePublishedPagesOnly":true}}
```

and get the response similar to:

```
{
    "d": "<tcm:ContainingPages xmlns:tcm=\"http:\/\/www.tridion.com\/ContentManager\/5.0\" ID=\"tcm:1135-11570\">
        <tcm:Item ID=\"tcm:1135-11565-64\" Title=\"Homepage\" Path=\"\\400 Website\\Home\">
        <tcm:PublishTarget TargetTypeId=\"tcm:0-1005-65538\" TargetTypeTitle=\"Staging\" 
        Purpose=\"Staging\" IsPublished=\"true\" PublishedAt=\"2018-07-10T14:25:27\" \/>
        <\/tcm:Item>
        <\/tcm:ContainingPages>"
}
```

I would like to emulate this behaviour in a Core Service app.

Can this be done through the Core Service API? If so, how is this achieved?

I’ve tried using `Client.GetPublishUrl(ItemId, Purpose);` but this only works with Pages, Structure Groups and Publications.

I've also tried `Client.GetListPublishInfo(ComponentId);`, but this only gives details if the Component is published as part of a Dynamic Component Presentation.

**NOTE:** I could obviously do this by recursively doing a 'Where used' on the Component(s) until I get a list of Pages and then seeing whether they're published, but was hoping that there was a simpler mechanism.

---

### Update:

Here is the working code based on the accepted answer that Neil gave:

```
void Main() {
    ResolveContainingPagesInstructionData instruction = new ResolveContainingPagesInstructionData() {
        IncludeComponentMetadataLinks = true,
        IncludeDynamicVersion = true,
        IncludePageMetadataLinks = true,
        IncludeWorkflow = true,
        ResolvePublishedPagesOnly = true
    };

    ContainingPagesDictionary dictionary = Client.ResolveContainingPages("tcm:1135-11570", instruction);
    dictionary.Dump();

    foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys.OrderBy(k => k.Item.Title))
    {
        string publishUrl = Client.GetPublishUrl(key.Item.IdRef, "Staging");
        Console.WriteLine($"{key.Item.Title} ({key.Item.IdRef}) - {publishUrl}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jon,

I believe under the covers that the Core Service method **ResolveContainingPages** is used:

```
ContainingPagesDictionary ResolveContainingPages(
    string componentId,
    ResolveContainingPagesInstructionData instruction
)
```

*componentId*

- Type: System.String
- TCM URI or WebDAV URL of a component.

*instruction*

- Type: Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.ResolveContainingPagesInstructionData
- An instance of ResolveContainingPagesInstructionData with set of options that configure resolving.

Returns a set of pages where component is directly or indirectly (via component links) used. If page is published, the associated set of publish info is also returned (one PublishInfoData instance per publish destination).